# Zoom support in android version 4.3 or lower is not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a web view as part of one of the activities and was trying to enable zoom in it but it doesn't work for lower versions of android.

```
 WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
  settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
  settings.setSupportZoom(true);
  settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

This code works fine for android version 4.4 or higher. What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class TweakedWebView extends WebView {

    private ZoomButtonsController zoomButtons;

    public TweakedWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TweakedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TweakedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        } else {
            try {
                Method method = getClass()
                        .getMethod("getZoomButtonsController");
                zoomButtons = (ZoomButtonsController) method.invoke(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // pass
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        if (zoomButtons != null) {
            zoomButtons.setVisible(false);
            zoomButtons.getZoomControls().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside override method `onTouchEvent` put this

```
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```